# Examples of non-unitary CFT described by QFT fixed point

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory

Are there examples of non-unitary CFTs that have a description in terms of some perturbative QFT approach in $d>2$? (I'd be happy with a bad one due to strong coupling.) Something like the epsilon expansion which we have for many unitary CFTs.

Would this require a non-unitary QFT as the starting point? Do these make sense?(Mathematically, they clearly don't describe fundamental interactions but could give an effective description of physical systems).

Comment: The epsilon expansion itself is non-unitary! That is, the Wilson-Fisher fixed point is non-unitary for non-integer dimensions: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00013

Comment: Agreed. Good example. How about examples for integer dimensions?

Comment: A non-unitary CFT in the UV makes just as much sense as a non-unitary CFT in the IR so this is one construction. The Lee-Yang model is an example. There are also examples where you start off with something unitary and the fixed point coupling just happens to not be real. This leads to what https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11512 calls a complex CFT.